# How to define the running task icon?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, java, icons

I'm running Gnome 3.36.1 under Ubuntu 20.04. In the Gnome desktop file I have defined an icon 'myIcon' and this appears in the menu and on the extension "TaskBar 2020" favorites list. However when running the task reverts in the task list to the standard Java icon 'Duke' and I can't differentiate between the various Java apps. 
So, how/where can I define the icon to be used for a running app task?

Answer (score 0):

Open the launch file with a text editor. Find the line with `Icon`

```
Icon = app_name.
```

After the sign is equal to write the path to our icon

```
Icon = /home/user/icons/icon.png
```

Save and reload Xes or pc.

Comment: Thank you, but as I pointed out in my original post I've already done that and it works, but not for the running task.